# How to record audio with visualizer graph view in android?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I need to show **Visualizer graph** with *recording audio*.

**Audio record** with showing effects in **graph**.

Graph like this.

[image]

Please help me If anyone have solution of that. I try to find most but not getting any proper solution for that.

Comment: See this link to github : https://github.com/tyorikan/voice-recording-visualizer

Answer (score 4):

Try my project https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Audio-Recorder-Visualization-Master

It looks like this

Recorder

[image]

PlayBack

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this MIT library https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer, and custom your own.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for giving this solution. I have already this but It is worked with play any audio media not for working with recording audio. because It currently contains the MediaPlayer and we need to use MediaRecorder with getting solution for Visualizer graph.

Comment: If You have any solution related to Record Audio with visualizer graph than please tell me. Because Record and Play Audio both working with different Media object and In recording media object not contains some methods which is used for visualizer graph in MediaPlayer to play the audio.

Comment: I have no experience on this. you can take a look on this library https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording/ . I take a look quickly on this lib, it uses bar graph, but you can copy other types of graph from above lib (felixpalmer lib) and do a test. I think it will work. Regards !